# Runtime Error 438 when using VB6 procedures

Tags: vb6, runtime-error

From what I understand about runtime error 438, it indicates binary compatibility problems like a referenced ActiveX library is not compatible with the distributed library. I can see no reason why this runtime error would be generated for basic VB6 procedures like `CLng` or `Round`.

```
Dim X as Integer
Dim Y as Single
Dim result as Long

X = GetX() ' Returns 0
Y = GetY() ' Returns 0.75

result = CLng(X / Y)  ' throws runtime error 438
result = Round(X / Y) ' throws runtime error 438
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

EDIT:

I have confirmed that the problem lies in the project, not the code. It seems that this error/situation is a quirk specific to the development environment offered by General Electric's Proficy iFIX 8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried out your code in vb6 and it worked fine.

You mention 2 errors in your post, 438 and 483.
VB6 help gives the following descriptions for those errors:

**Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)**

**Printer driver does not support specified property (Error 483)**

I can't see how either of those errors are being raised

Answer (score -1):

Integer division against a Single will return an integer. Your variable "result" is declared as long. With Integers in division, you should use the other slash ( \ ) also.

Comment: But shouldn't `CLng` covert it to a `Long` regardless? And `Round` returns a `Variant` type so I don't see any problems with letting the compiler figuring out the cast.